# Will BF4 BETA work with 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, beta

I would like to know if battlefield 4 beta will work with Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bit).
If it does will someone tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: The only way it could work would be using PlayOnLinux (http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

Answer (score 2):

Battlefield 4 Beta will not work on Ubuntu 13.04. According to the [Battlefield 4 Beta test results](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23058) on WineHQ Applications Database Battlefield 4 Beta got a Garbage rating because of freezing, slow frame rate and erratic mouse behavior; all of which makes the game unplayable.

[Battlefield 4 Digital Deluxe Edition's rating](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16433) with Wine 1.7 at WineHQ Applications Database is also Garbage.